# Finding point where angular bisector meets circumcircle in complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

If $A(z_1)$,$b(z_2)$ and $C(z_3)$ are vertices of a triangle. It is inscribed in circle |z|=2. If internal angular bisector of A meets the circumcircle at $D(z_4)$. Find $z_4$ interms of $z_1$,$z_2$ and $z_3$.

I knew that angle subtended by a chord at circum center is twice angle subtended at center. I am confused how to use for which triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle bisector from $A$ meet the circumcircle of $ABC$ in the midpoint of the $BC$-arc, hence, assuming the origin is in the circumcenter of $ABC$:
$$ z_4 = \sqrt{z_2 z_3}.$$

Comment: The square-root is a multi-valued function in the complex numbers, so you need to be careful as to which square-root you choose. Depending on this choice, it could be the intersection of either the internal angle bisector or external bisector with the circumcircle.

Comment: @cmtappu96: nope, wait, depending on which square root we take, we get the midpoint of the minor $BC$-arc or the antipodal point, i.e. the midpoint of the major $BC$-arc.